# Half of my view disappear after CATransform3DRotate

Tags: ios, catransform3drotate

I have 1 view, in this view I have 1 UIImageView and UILabel, when I rotate my view half of view disappear.

This is my code

viewToAnimate is the view cointains image and label.

```
CATransform3D _3Dt = CATransform3DRotate(viewToAnimate.layer.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(beginValue), 0.0, 1.0, 0);
_3Dt.m34 = 1.0 / -300;

viewToAnimate.layer.transform = _3Dt;

CATransform3D _scale;

if (needZoom) {
    _scale = CATransform3DScale(viewToAnimate.layer.transform , 1+scale, 1+scale, 1+scale);

    if (_scale.m11 > 1) {
        _scale.m11 = 1;
        _scale.m22 = 1;
        _scale.m33 = 1;
    }
}
else  {
    _scale = CATransform3DScale(viewToAnimate.layer.transform , 1-scale, 1-scale, 1-scale);
}

viewToAnimate.layer.transform = _scale;
//viewToAnimate.layer.zPosition = sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(beginValue)*MOSAIC_WIDTH)+1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the value of DEGREES_TO_RADIANS? Is it by any chance M_PI/2?
Your code tells that you are rotating around y-axis. See last 3 parameters in first line:

```
0.0, 1.0, 0
```

If you are supplying this then this is expected behavior - consider a plane facing you and imagine it rotate around y-axis by +/- 90 degrees, it will definitely disappear.

Comment: DEGREES_TO_RADIANS is DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0). Before add UIImageView, this code works fine, but when I add UIImageView I have this bug.

The rotacion work with finger move. I call this code in touchesMoved: and the max rotation when I slide the 320px is 80º

Comment: Which view are you rotating? What is its z-position relative to imageview?

Comment: I move the container view, this view have 2 subview. And if I call viewToAnimate.layer.zPosition, 0 is the return value

This is screenshot of my app when I start it: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9014142/IMG_0129.PNG

And when I move: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9014142/IMG_0130.PNG

Comment: I find the solution, my view disappear is due to the background UIImageView, need to set zposition of backgorund image to -400.

Comment: glad you found. If my answer helped, mark correct which will increase your correction ratio and help you get quicker answers in future.

Comment: @Diego : Thanks !! I faced the same problem and your comment helped.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Diego's comment on the other answer this can be caused by zPosition issues. Make your view above all the others by setting it's zPosition to a higher value.